# Magento 2 : How to add OTP functionality attach with Cash On Delivery Payment option?

Tags: magento2, overrides, payment-methods

I need to validate mobile number in case of Cash On Delivery option. How do we override this payment option to get this done Or we can call any event for this functionality in Magento 2 ?

Comment: You can use a custom module , with plugin to intercept

Comment: Can you please explain me with some example or give me some brief like which event we can use for that or which file or code we have to override ?

Comment: Got this one, https://magecomp.com/magento-2-sms-notification.html
Need some customization i think